# How do I jump from while(getline(cin,tmp))?

Tags: c++, stl, io

I am reading 'generic programming and the stl'

in chapter1, this is a sample like this,

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    string tmp;

    while(getline(cin,tmp))  //problem is here, it keep asking me to input value
        v.push_back(tmp);

    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
 }
```

how do I get out of the while, it keep asking me to input value, no ending....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send an end-of-file character: you can use CTRL-Z Return (Windows), or CTRL-D (Unix terminals). Then, `getline` will return false as there is nothing more to read from `stdin`.

An alternative is: pipe the output of another program into this one.

Comment: `cin` != `stdin`, even if they point to the same low level handle/descriptor/whatever.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, but `stdin` the C `FILE*` pointer is different from "standard input" the concept, the stream of input being supplied to your program from the host environment.  Benoit is referring to the latter.

Comment: @Adam Rosenield: that was indeed what I was talking about, didn't intend to use the `stdin` from the C headers.

Answer (score 5):

Your program asks for input until it reaches the [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file). Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on UNIX-like systems or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows to send EOF to indicate end of input.

Comment: @Rob: use < kbd >XXX</ kbd > for them: <kbd>Foo</kbd><kbd>Bar!</kbd>, edit: not working in comments ...

Answer (score 0):

Because your not comparing anything basically in your while loop you only gave an iterator not a condition for exit.

So add a var and increment your loop to say 5 after five iterations it should exit

```
int x=0;
While(getline(cin,tmp),x!=5){
     //other code

 x++;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but I think the key of the problem is the EOF flag.